# Angular 11 ng build --prod --aot stuck on generating browser application bundles (phase: building)

Tags: angular-cli

I Update angular version from 10 to 11 every things about build and serve is ok and work correctly but have problem in ng build --prod --aot that stuck on building phase......

[image: build image]